# Proving $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. ISI PCB 2020

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, alternative-proof

**Question:** Prove that the function $f(x)$ defined as $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2$$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, for any real number $x$.

**My Attempt:** Given $\epsilon$ and a fixed real number $x_0$, choose $$\delta(\epsilon, x_0)=\frac{\epsilon}{\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_0^{n-1}\times 2x_0^n}{(n-1)!n!}\right|+1}$$
Then,
$$|x-x_0|<\delta
\\\Rightarrow |x-x_0|\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_0^{n-1}\times 2x_0^n}{(n-1)!n!}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_0^{n-1}\times 2x_0^n}{(n-1)!n!}\right|+1}\times\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_0^{n-1}\times 2x_0^n}{(n-1)!n!}\right|<\epsilon
\\\Rightarrow \left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\left(\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)^2-\left(\frac{x_0^n}{n!}\right)\right)^2\right|<\epsilon
\\\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$
Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous for $x_0$. But since $x_0$ was arbitrary. Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous for $\mathbb{R}$

Any mistakes in my proof? Please correct me. Also, if there is any other way to prove $f(x)$ is continuous? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The series converges uniformly in $[-N,N]$ by M-test so the sum is continuous. This is true for each $N$ so $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: R-ISI PCB... what is that?

Comment: @Buraian Title edited. My bad for the confusion.

Comment: Do you have to check that the series actually make sense for all $x\in \mathbb R$?

Comment: @Gary For every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_0|\le n_0$. Therefore, for $n\ge 2n_0^3$, we have the $\sum_{n\ge 2n_0^3}\frac{2x_0^{2n-1}}{(n-1)!n!}<\sum_{n\ge 2n_0^3}\frac{1}{n^2}$. The latter is convergent. So the series is convergent. Hence, it makes sense. Am I correct?

Comment: @Kumar I cannot understand your estimation. How about a simple ratio test?

Comment: @Gary By simple ratio test, we have this $\frac{x_0^2}{n(n+1)}$. Now, as $n\to\infty$, we have the limit to be $0$. So, this series converges.

Comment: @Kumar Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The following theorem is well known
Theorem : Let $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of functions with common domain $X$ and suppose that $f_n$ is continuous at $c \in X$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ uniformly converges to the sum function $f(x)$ then $f$ is continuous at $c$.

All you need to check is that your series is uniformly convergent.

Comment: I would add that uniform convergence has to be checked in a neighbourhood of $c$.